# Rename true false boolean

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, boolean

Was wondering if there is a way to change a boolean from true / false to in / out?

My code below is a boolean switch but I want it to print in or out not 0 or 1

```
    while True:
       Tag = raw_input("Please Scan your Tag: ")
       q = "SELECT * FROM CARDS WHERE TAG=?"
       up = "UPDATE CARDS SET FLAG = (CASE WHEN FLAG=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) WHERE TAG=?"
       cursor.execute(q, (Tag,))
       cursor.execute(up, (Tag,))
       conn.commit()
       for row in cursor:
         print row [1] + " has been checked " + row[3]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `'in' if condition else 'out'`:

```
print row [1] + " has been checked " + ('in' if row[3] else 'out')
```

Comment: So would that look like. 'in' if flag =1? Can you post example please

Comment: @shaggs Python automatically converts zero to `False` and non-zero to `True`. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
print row [1] + " has been checked " + row[3]
```

Try:

```
print row [1] + " has been checked " + ("in" if row[3] else "out")
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but beaten to the punch